# Electron - Error con rpm "el campo License debe estar presente en el paquete: (main package)"

Tags: javascript, json, nodejs, electron, rpm

Yo me instale el modulo de Electron Redhat (rpm) Installer porque quiero compilar en RPM, entonces ya coloque el codigo en el package.json como en la página de Github de este modulo. Pero a la hora de colocar "npm run rpm64" me sale esto:

> Error: Error executing command (1): 
>   rpmbuild -bb /tmp/electron-11811-14445-jo2hue.ifa6c/WhatsApp-Linux_1.0.0_x86_64/SPECS/WhatsApp-Linux.spec --target x86_64
>   error: el campo License debe estar presente en el paquete: (main package)

No se porque este error sucede e investigue en todos lados para ver alguna solución para esto pero no encontre nada. Solo vi en otros lenguajes que usan nodejs este error pero no en Electron.

Comment: probablemente por que el campo  `license` esta vacio o no existe en el `package.json` verificalo.

Comment: Intente con eso igual y todavía me salía eso.